# SQL - need help writing/modifying MYSQL query

Tags: mysql

There are two columns :

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 401 | Ruby |
| 402 | Diamond |
| 403 | Ruby |
| 401 | Ruby |

I want to find the columns where a is common but b is repeats

But B Column Value "Ruby" should come along with 401 at Column A Value "401".

I want to find out the records where "Ruby" is assigned other than Columna "401"

How can I do it ?

Comment: sorry i didnt undestand anything. can you edit the post, add some detail like your table , expected result ?

Comment: There is two columns engine_no and chasis_no..Engine and Chasis_No is unique. For instance Engine n0 123,Chasis_no is 321 .. I want to find out chasis no 321  is  assigned to engine no other than 123

Comment: As I understand you need a) find duplicated rows b) return the rows which have the same `B` but different `A`.. is it?

Comment: Yes Sir,You are right

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need in this?

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM table t1
JOIN ( SELECT t2.a, t2.b
       FROM table t2
       GROUP BY a, b
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) t3 USING (b)
WHERE t1.a <> t3.a
```

---

It is possible that the pairs selected in the subquery interferes by `b`. In this case the query will give wrong output, and you need in

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM table t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM table t2
                   WHERE t1.a <> t2.a AND t1.b = t2.b
                   GROUP BY t2.a, t2.b
                   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 )
```

Comment: It is showing syntax error.Just changing table name

Comment: @NarayanaSwamy This is a pattern. And `table` is placeholder, not object name.